# AspNetCore 2.0.5 Add-Migration trying to create table instead of alter existing

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

AspNetCore.All 2.0.5 decided to Create a new table for a migration with the same name as one that already exists, instead of altering the existing table.

`Add-Migration` produces a migration successfully, but when running `Update-Database` it throws an error because a **table with the same name already exists**.

I can drop the table at this point in development or manually fix the script but that doesn't help me in the long run. I need to understand whats going on here for future migrations.

This was the initial migration that was applied. DB only had this one table.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GameApplication.Migrations
{
    public partial class first : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "UserProfiles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserProfiles", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "UserProfiles");
        }
    }
}
```

Then after a new add-migration it includes this:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "UserProfiles",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            Country = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            DisplayName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            Langauge = table.Column<float>(nullable: false),
            LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            Latitude = table.Column<float>(nullable: false),
            Longitude = table.Column<float>(nullable: false),
            UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserProfiles", x => x.Id);
        });
```

- Its like it has completely ignored that the previous migration exists; there is no mention of the fact that `Name` was removed and replaced with `FirstName LastName` which would normally show the data loss warning. What would cause that to happen?

Seemingly related unanswered question:
[Add-Migration not adding column to existing table in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731604/add-migration-not-adding-column-to-existing-table-in-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this while writing the question, so:

EF figures out how to create new migrations based on the `ApplicationContextModelSnapshot.cs` and this file was not correct in my case.

This snapshot file was broken for me, because my `20180313134743_first.Designer.cs` file had been modified and commented. Which meant that EF was unable to properly create the snapshot or it didn't exist, making it unaware of the current model state when it tried to make a new migration.

**To resolve it:**

1. I discarded the new migration with `remove-migration` command.
2. Manually fixed the Snapshot - by copying the contents of `20180313134743_first.Designer.cs BuildTargetModel()` into `ApplicationContextModelSnapshot.cs BuildModel()`
3. Ran `Update-Database` to verify and then `Add-Migration` and this time it successfully recognized that it needed to alter the existing table.